# Database Table Creation

Tags: database-schema

I am supposed to create a website application for calls, where the user has to enter the details of the calls he gets that day.

Problem I'm facing is with the tables that I have to create to store these calls in the database.

Am I supposed to create  a new table for each day (date), or do I have to enter the same date in the same table? Is there any possibility to make two tables, one for date and other for all other details and whenever required get the details of particular date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I supposed to create a new table for each day (date), or do I have to enter the same date in the same table?

You only have one table, and that table will have a field that stores the date. A simple example would be:

```
CallId  DateOfCall              Caller
------  --------------------    ------------------
1       15/07/2013 13:31:20     John Smith
2       15/07/2013 14:18:37     Jim Hendrix
3       16/07/2013 12:01:37     Steve Jeffers
```

DBMS (DataBase Management Systems, e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL) are *very* good at filtering rows in a table based on criteria like dates.

---

> Is there any possibility to make two tables, one for date and other for all other details and whenever required get the details of particular date?

You *can* do this, but it's not obvious that there would be any reason to. The date/time of the call is tied implicitly to the call itself, so would sensibly be stored in the same table (as per my example above).

Comment: Thank You so much for the reply and help. I'm a beginner in this. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

1 table is adequate in this case.
For exemple : idCall | numberCall | dateCall

Comment: Although your answer is correct, I suspect the OP has a fundamental misunderstanding, which your answer doesn't take into account.

Answer (score 0):

The questions are fundamental. Best if you learn the basiscs of database designs. You will find a load of literature about this topic. A first online introduction may be found for example at http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/fundamentalsofrelationaldatabasedesign.aspx .

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for your reply. I'll surely do that . Thanks for the website mentioned